# Try-Catch vs re throwing an exception?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, throw, throws

I have a function fun1(), which calls fun2(), which might throw an Exception :

```java
public <T> T fun1(final String abc) throws XYZException {
    try {

        fun2()

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new XYZException();
    }
}
```

1. If we are re-throwing the exception, does try catch make sense here?
2. Should we add throws in the method definition line?

Comment: My opinion is that catching and re-throwing is not handling anything.  One thing that might be acceptable would be wrapping a caught exception with a custom uncaught one, but I'm generally not in favor.

Comment: That entirely depends on the specific situation, and whether having a more specific exception adds value.

Comment: @duffymo So you would rather a method threw an (imaginary) `LowLevelKernelException` than an `IOException` when the user unplugs the USB pendrive mid-access? I strongly disagree: failure to wrap exceptions leaks implementation details and should be frowned upon in the same way as failure to mark private methods `private`.

Comment: Fair point, @KonradRudolph.  I said "generally not in favor", but that was not meant to be a blanket condemnation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you converting a general `Exception` in the more specific one `XYZException`. If this is the aim, it can make sense. Especially if `XYZException` is a user defined exception that helps to narrow the error down.

On reason could be, that a other (more upper) error handler specifically catches the `XYZException` and handles it. While if it would have thrown the general `Exception` it does not know how to handle it.

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
      fun1<Type>("String");
    } catch (final XYZException e) {
      //Recover to XYZException or do something else specific to XYZException 
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      // Log the error and end the program, as we don't know how to recover
    }
```

For Example: As fun1 is a generic function, if `fun1<Type1>("..")` throws an XYZException you could for example try again with `fun1<Type2>("..")`. Both, fun1 and fun2 do not know what Type2 would be so they can't recover on their own.